# fill in bg color based on button clicking in android

Tags: android

I have a variable webColor that I want to fill with a color code if that button is pressed, so the imageView on the next page (subHeader) will be the same color as the button.

I am getting these errors

```
05-19 22:54:15.725    2050-2050/com.dredaydesigns.dredaycreativeportfolio E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.dredaydesigns.dredaycreativeportfolio, PID: 2050
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dredaydesigns.dredaycreativeportfolio/com.dredaydesigns.dredaycreativeportfolio.content_activity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.dredaydesigns.dredaycreativeportfolio.content_activity.onCreate(content_activity.java:13)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.dredaydesigns.dredaycreativeportfolio.content_activity.onCreate(content_activity.java:13)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f090051}
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2068)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3554)
            at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:123)
            at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:119)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.dredaydesigns.dredaycreativeportfolio.content_activity.onCreate(content_activity.java:13)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and here is my code

```
package com.dredaydesigns.dredaycreativeportfolio;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public String webColor;
    private Button mWebButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       mWebButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.webButton);

        mWebButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String webColor = mWebButton.getText().toString();
                Intent goToNext = new Intent(MainActivity.this,content_activity.class);
                goToNext.putExtra(webColor,"#C41E72");
                startActivity(goToNext);

            }
        });


    }}
```

content_activity.java

```
package com.dredaydesigns.dredaycreativeportfolio;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

import static com.dredaydesigns.dredaycreativeportfolio.R.layout.activity_content_activity;

public class content_activity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(activity_content_activity);



}}
```

activity_content_activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context="com.dredaydesigns.dredaycreativeportfolio.content_activity"
                android:background="#0e6fa2">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/pageBanner"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/webactivityheader02"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/subBanner"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pageBanner"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pageBanner"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/pageBanner"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:background="@string/webColor"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MainActivity"
                android:background="@drawable/mainactivity01"
                android:clickable="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:background="@drawable/dredaylogo"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/webButton"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/webButton"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/webButton"
        android:alpha="100"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/web"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/interactiveButton"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/interactiveButton"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/interactiveButton"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:alpha="200"
        android:layout_below="@+id/webButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/interactive"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mobileButton"
        android:alpha="100"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/mobile"
        android:layout_below="@+id/interactiveButton"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/interactiveButton"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/interactiveButton"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/creativeButton"
        android:alpha="100"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/creative"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mobileButton"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mobileButton"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/mobileButton"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/strategyButton"
        android:alpha="100"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/strategy"
        android:layout_below="@+id/creativeButton"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/creativeButton"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/creativeButton"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/contentButton"
        android:alpha="100"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/strategyButton"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/strategyButton"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/strategyButton"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:background="@drawable/mainactivity05"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:background="@drawable/mainactivity04"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Does the app crash when you click the button or when you start the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you have to replace `"@string/webColor"` in the  activity_content_activity  xml with #c41e72 like below

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.dredaydesigns.dredaycreativeportfolio.content_activity"
            android:background="#0e6fa2">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/pageBanner"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@drawable/webactivityheader02"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/subBanner"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pageBanner"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pageBanner"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/pageBanner"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="#c41e72"/>
```

if you want to set it programmatically, write the below code

in MainActivity do pass your color the below way

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
public String webColor= "webColor";
private Button mWebButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   mWebButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.webButton);

    mWebButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           // String webColor = mWebButton.getText().toString();
            Intent goToNext = new Intent(MainActivity.this,content_activity.class);
            goToNext.putExtra(webColor,"#C41E72");
            startActivity(goToNext);

        }
    });


}}
```

and in content_activity activity,

```
 public class content_activity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(activity_content_activity);
    String backgroundColor = intent.getExtras().getString("webColor");
    ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.subBanner);
    iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(backgroundColor));


}}
```

and

Comment: oooh thank you so much I think I totally get it now thanks to you! So you have to start it with some value that satisfies the string requirements and also pass it through then to override it?

Comment: i get this problem as it cant find the intent we are referencing in the content_activity ' activity.C:\Users\Andreas\Downloads\dredaycreativeportfolio\app\src\main\java\com\dredaydesigns\dredaycreativeportfolio\content_activity.java
Error:(17, 34) error: cannot find symbol variable intent
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details. '

Comment: oooh got it to work! added get infront of intent! thank you for helping meeee!! wahoo!!